# How do you wrap C++ code for IronPython access

Tags: python, c++, ironpython, swig, cpython

I have a simple example which I want to access from Ironpython (I am coming from 'regular/sane' python') so I am struggling importing my C++ code into Ironpython. Normally I just use SWIG, wrap my code, import and go on my merry way

But with Ironpython being C# and not C based it makes this process much harder

How do I wrap this class for ironpython 
(I also attached my swig file for this example, but that might not be useful)

```
#include "minimal.h"


double average(std::vector<int> v) {
    return std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0.0) / v.size();
}

std::vector<double> half(const std::vector<double>& v) {
    std::vector<double> w(v);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i<w.size(); i++)
        w[i] /= 2.0;
    return w;
}

void halve_in_place(std::vector<double>& v) {
    std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(),
        std::bind2nd(std::divides<double>(), 2.0));
}
```

with the header file

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <numeric>

double average(std::vector<int> v);

std::vector<double> half(const std::vector<double>& v);

void halve_in_place(std::vector<double>& v);
```

I had a swig i file minimal.i   but realize there are numerous issues issuing a swig.exe -c++ -python "%(FullPath)" on this and having ironpython actually accept it on import.

```
%module transfervector
%{
#include "minimal.h"
%}

%include "std_vector.i"
// Instantiate templates used by example
namespace std {
   %template(IntVector) vector<int>;
   %template(DoubleVector) vector<double>;
}

// Include the header file with above prototypes
%include "minimal.h"
```

Answer (score 2):

SWIG-python isn't going to work - it generates CPython extensions, and IronPython doesn't support those.

Ultimately you'll need to wrap the C++ so that it's accessible from .NET. I think you can use SWIG to generate C# wrappers, which you could then import into IronPython. Otherwise, you might be able to compile with the C++/CLI compiler to generate a .NET assembly directly, which can also be used from IronPython.

Comment: @Joe, you could further explain if you have full control over the C++ code or if it is provided to you as a compiled library (as that would rule out the CLI path). Have a look at http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html which has a minimal example on c#/c++ pinvoking which will give you what you need for IronPython as well.

Comment: Full control of the code .. I guess its the c# DLL part I could not get working when I tried the C# tutorial, so I was looking a minimal example like the one I had I could expand on just to see the pipeline in action! thanks!